# Python - Check if numbers in list are factors of a number

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, factors

I have a `list` of numbers (`integers`) (say, from 1 to 10).

They're not necessarily consecutive, but they are in ascending order.

I've prompted the user multiple times to enter a choice of the available numbers. When that number is entered, it is removed from the list along with any of its *factors* that may be there.

I've prevented the user from selecting prime numbers. However, at some point in time, there may be non-prime numbers there, which have no factors remaining.

I'm relatively new to Python, so I'm having trouble implementing:

- Checking if the number selected has no factors remaining (even if it is not prime).
- Checking if only prime numbers remain, or numbers without
  factors.

I'm thinking of using `for` statements, but I'm not sure exactly how to implement them. Can anyone offer advice, or code? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if there are any factors of the number `guess` remaining you can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
hasfactors = any(guess % n == 0 for n in numbers)
```

To check if all the remaining numbers are prime, [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) can be used. (Since you say you already prevented the user from inputting prime numbers I assume you have some kind of `isprime()` function):

```
onlyprimes = all(isprime(n) for n in numbers)
```

Comment: All the comments were helpful, but I utilised your OnlyPrimes method, and found the all() method handy for other uses. Thanks! And you predicted right, I did have an IsPrime() function...

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, you could use list comprehensions to build a new list where each element is not the number selected and not a factor of the number selected (see code). Compare this with your original list.

```
$ python
>>> selected_number = 6
>>> [x for x in range(1,11) if selected_number % x]
[4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

For the second problem, check if each element is prime. If not, check for numbers without factors; for each element, you might `mod` over the original list and check if it's a list of zeros. I'm sure there's a faster way, though.

Answer (score 1):

If L is a list of non-zero numbers, the list of those which are factors of a number N is:

```
factors = [x for x in L if N % x == 0]
```

The list will simply be empty if N has no factors in L, of course.

I'm not sure what you mean by "numbers without factors", unless you mean "primes" (?) -- there have been several SO questions and answers on checking primality in Python, I'd use `gmpy.is_prime` (from my extension [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/)) but then of course I'm biased;-).

If you mean, "all numbers that have no factors in L", well, there's infinitely many of them, so it's kind of hard to make a list of them all.  An unbounded generator for them:

```
import itertools

def nofactorsinlist(L):
  for i in itertools.count():
    if any(x for x in L if i % x == 0):
      continue
    yield i
```

Some optimizations would be possible, but this one is really simple and I'm loath to add complicated optimizations without understanding exactly what it is that you're after!-)